# How to SAVE edited Treeview node text in C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I am trying  to edit treeview node names in a treeview (they become editable on a button click ) and then I want them to remain saved (if I exit and enter the aplication again, the new, edited names should be displayed), BUT they always revert to the original name(text) on program reentering.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.LabelEdit = true;
    }
```

Questions is how to make the new treeview node names be saved after editing, so when I enter the aplication again they don't reset to the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event on application shutdown to manually iterate over the TreeView and save the data to a file. Then when  you applications starts again read them and populate the TreeView.

Comment: I was thinking theres a more straight forward way, I know I can do it via an external file (ex database), thankyou anyway :).

Comment: I don't think there is a more straight forward way because the data is lost when you close the program so you have to store it. Using a database is a little bit to much. But you can do it simply by using a normal txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit your project by modifying the developped program runtime.

Comment: The only way to do that is to save tree structure to a file f.w. with serialization (the fastest way) and load it on app's start, but you won't see those changes in VS.